# When is an SDE solution differentiable in its starting value?

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $W=\{W_t\}_{t\in[0;T]}$ be a real-valued Brownian motion, $\{F_t\}_{t\in [0;T]}$ the filtration generated by $W$, augmented with the nullsets, $\mu,\sigma\colon [0;T]\times\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ measurable functions with some proper conditions such that, for all $t \in [0;T]$ and $x \in \mathbb R$, there is a unique stochastic process $\{X^{t,x}_s\}_{s\in[t;T]}$ satisfying
$$
\mathrm d X^{t,x}_s = \mu(s,X^{t,x}_s) \mathrm ds + \sigma(s,X^{t,x}_s) \mathrm dW_s,
\quad
X^{t,x}_t = x.
$$
If we fix $s \in (t;T]$ and a random outcome $\omega$, under which stronger conditions can we say that $x \mapsto X^{t,x}_s(\omega)$ is differentiable? Is there literature on this question? Thank you!

Comment: Good terms to google for are: flow of diffeomorphism, Stratovich SDE, rough paths. From a very brief look it appears to me that (assuming sufficient regularity for $\mu$) the regularity of the flow $x\mapsto X_{s}^{t,x}(\omega)$ is the one of $\sigma$ minus 2. So for differentiaility, you will need at least $\sigma\in C^{3}$

Comment: Stratonovich integrals? My question was only about Itô integrals.

Comment: They transform into each other, under appropriate regularity conditions.

Comment: You may want to give a look at this paper and references therein (in particular the articles by Kunita, Malliavin ,Bismut) http://archive.numdam.org/article/SPS_1982__16__490_0.pdf